# How to minimize colors on graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph on $n$ vertices, is there a way to determine the least number of colors necessary such that each clique of order three either

1. shows a proper vertex coloring, or
2. contains only one color,

given that we use at least three colors?

Comment: This is interesting, but this sounds like a hard problem. Does this question fit into some broader context? Is there anything that leads you to think there's a reasonable way to calculate the number?

Comment: In my Intro to Knot Theory class, my buddy and I came up with an invariant of knots that resembles tricolorability. If one makes a graph G where each vertex represents an arc and there is an edge between vertices v and w iff v and w meet at a crossing, then the problem of determining the invariant property associated with the knot is equivalent to the problem I posed above. I have no reason to believe that there is an easy solution to it, it's more of a pet project since its inception.

Comment: If I understand your rules, a tetrahedral graph $K_4$ requires four colors, one for each vertex.

Comment: @hardmath You would be correct. Each clique of order 3 in $K_4$ can either be properly vertex colored or each vertex  is the same color. If any aforementioned clique contained 3 vertices of the same color in $K_4$, then any other clique would have the same property and the resulting colored graph would violate the rule that at least three colors must be used.

Comment: The problem can be reduced to coloring graphs which consist (in a sense) of $3$-cliques that are "edge" connected.  Perhaps the required number of colors for such a "component" is related to the usual (vertex) coloring of a derived graph in which nodes correspond to $3$-cliques of the original graph.

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean? What do you mean when you say that the $3$-cliques would be "edge" connected or when you say that a derived graph would have nodes corresponding to $3$-cliques of the original graph?

Comment: I'm working on a write-up.  It's too long for a Comment, but you can see my progress [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5101/3111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show the described coloring problem reduces to one in which the required minimum coloring is the same as a proper vertex coloring of a connected graph in which every edge belongs to a triangle ($3$-clique).

The problem is to "determine the least number of colors" which can be assigned to the $n$ vertices of a simple graph $G$ so that in each of its $3$-cliques, the three vertices are either monochromatic or *properly* colored (distinct colors for neighbors) *provided* that at least three colors are assigned.  Let's call this the *Harry* number of $G$, symbolically $H(G)$, and refer to the allowable colorings with at least three colors as *Harry colorings*.

If $n\lt 3$ it is impossible to assign three colors, so the Harry number $H(G)$ is technically undefined in those cases.  In view of this we assume hereafter $n\ge 3$.

Clearly $n$ colors always suffice in such a coloring (by assigning a different color to each vertex).  More precisely $H(G) \le \max(\chi(G),3)$, i.e. the Harry number is bounded above by the maximum of [the chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Chromatic_number) of $G$ and $3$.  An example of this bound being sharp is $G = K_n$, so $H(K_n) = \chi(K_n) = n$.

*Proposition*  Let $G_0$ be the subgraph of $G$ with the same vertices but removing all edges that do not belong to any $3$-clique (triangle) of $G$.  Then $H(G_0) = H(G)$.

*Proof* By construction the $3$-cliques of $G$ and $G_0$ are the same.  Thus any Harry coloring of $G$ induces a Harry coloring of subgraph $G_0$, and $H(G_0) \le H(G)$.  On the other hand any Harry coloring of $G_0$ extends to a Harry coloring of $G$ since the edges added back are not part of any $3$-clique of $G$.  Therefore the reverse inequality holds, and $H(G_0) = H(G)$.

Note that if $G_0$ has at least three connected components, then $H(G) = H(G_0) = 3$ by choosing three distinct components and assigning a different monochromatic coloring to each of these (remaining components can also be colored mono-chromatically with any of the three colors).  Every $3$-clique is colored mono-chromatically, and exactly three colors are used.

If $G_0$ has two connected components, say $G_1$ and $G_2$, then at least one of them has enough vertices to admit a valid coloring (they cannot both be isolated nodes), and the number of colors required by $G_0$ is the minimum of the colors required by such validly colorable components.

Thus we can reduce consideration to a connected graph $G = G_0$ in which every edge belongs to a $3$-clique (triangle).  Note that in this simplified context the Harry number $H(G_0)$ is exactly the same as the chromatic number $\chi(G_0)$.